How to connect to docker daemon running on Windows 11 host from a Jenkins server running on WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04)
I am using a Windows 11 PC with docker desktop installed on the Windows host and Jenkins installed on WSL2 (Distro: Ubuntu 22.04)
I was configuring Jenkins cloud agent with "Docker 1.7.0" plugin. In the "Cloud docker Configuration" page, after inserting tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 as the "Docker Host URI", I am getting org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2375 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused error while testing the connection.
My Docker daemon setting from docker desktop:
I tried the following options:

Using tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 as mentioned above I get the following error


Using the output of ip route show | grep -i default | awk '{ print $3}' in the WSL2 Ubuntu



I have also checked that docker daemon is running and is listening on port 2375 in Windows Host using netstat -a -b on powershell prompt

What else can I do to make the connection successful?
